# Logic Pro X Forward and Rewind only moves a 128th note in one project

Tags: logic-pro

In one of my projects when I use the key command for 'Forward' and 'Rewind' ( '.' and ',') it only moves the playhead forward or back a 128th note rather than a bar.  Holding shift doesn't change this at all.

I have reset the Key Commands, and checked them - they are default.  In other projects the key commands work as expected (moving a bar forward or back).

What did I change in this one project that made it so Forward and Rewind only move a 128th note?

Update: the onscreen Forward and Rewind buttons on the transport also only move by a 128th note when clicked.

Comment: I don't have Logic, so I don't know what the exact problem is here, but most DAW's have the option to export the project settings. You could try to export all your project and general setting from the project that works and import the settings into the one where it doesn't work.
My guess is that you enabled any function that for examples uses the current grid of the project which is 128th or something similar.

Comment: That would probably work but ideally I'd like to know what happened as I have other project settings and its going to get pretty tedious pretty quick.  Also note I googled how to change the amount and most of what I've read indicates it can't be done - like forward and rewind is always a bar and if you want it different you have to setup some alternate custom key commands.